# how to make the backgroundimage to be covered whole page in reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs

Here is my coding link. The image is not covered for the whole page. https://codesandbox.io/embed/mystifying-hamilton-elg9i9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Add image in your parent div [example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/mystifying-hamilton-elg9i9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
position: "absolute",
top: 0,
left: 0,
```